# What values could go into parameter l2_regularization for HistGradientBoostingRegressor in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gradient-descent, hyperparameters, gridsearchcv

I am trying to tune hyperparameters for [HistGradientBoostingRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingRegressor,) in sklearn and would like to know what possible values could be for `l2_regularization`, the rest of the parameter grid that works for me looks like this -

```
param_grid = {
    'learning_rate': [.1, .12],
    'max_iter': [1000, 1200],
    'min_samples_leaf': [15, 20],
    'max_depth': [None, 10, 20]
}
```

Here the learning rate of .12 and 1000 iterations give good enough results. So I want to know what sort of values go for `l2_regularization`? are they `.1, .2` like learning rate or integers? As far as I understand l2 is for regularization penalty to reduce the variance in the model. Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, Regularizations are constraints that are added to the loss function. The model when minimizing the loss function will have to also minimize the regularization term. Hence, This will reduce the model variance as it cannot overfit.

Acceptable parameters for `l2_regularization` are often on a logarithmic scale between `0` and `0.1`, such as `0.1, 0.001, 0.0001`.